# Call a method in the parent of the parent ( the gran pa)

Tags: php, laravel, class

I am making a tournament generator plugin in laravel: https://github.com/xoco70/kendo-tournaments

So basically,

```
- a championship can be made with team or with competitors
- a championship can have preliminary round
- a championship can be Direct Elimination or PlayOff
```

I initially did it in a single class TreeGen, but there were a lot of :

`if ($championship->isDirectElimination)` or `if ($championship->hasPreliminary)`, etc... This can make a lot of case, and complexity increased too much. So, I refactored like this

SuperClass: `TreeGen`

This class has all common methods

Then 2 children class:

`DirectEliminationTreeGen extends TreeGen`

`PlayOffTreeGen extends TreeGen`

Then for each class, I created to children:

`DirectEliminationTeamTreeGen extends TreeGen`

`DirectEliminationCompetitorTreeGen extends TreeGen`

`PlayOffTreeTeamGen extends TreeGen`

`PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen extends TreeGen`

In each class, I only put method that vary.

This approach has for me several advantages :

- It break a single big class into smaller ones
- It removes conditions that make my code more and more difficult to maintain.

Now, my problem is in the case of DirectElimination with Team.

First, Before generating, I have a method `chooseGenerationStrategy` that determine the case:

```
public function chooseGenerationStrategy()
{
    $generation = new TreeGen($this, null);
    switch (true) {
        case $this->isDirectEliminationCompetitor():
            $generation = new DirectEliminationCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
        case $this->isDirectEliminationTeam():
            $generation = new DirectEliminationTeamTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
        case $this->isPlayoffCompetitor():
            $generation = new PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
        case $this->isPlayoffTeam():
            $generation = new PlayOffTeamTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
    }
    return $generation;
}
```

Then I execute `$generation->run()`

It appears that in the execution, I have in TreeGen:

```
    $byeGroup = $this->getByeGroup($this->championship, $fighters);
```

so in this case, $this is `DirectEliminationTeamTreeGen` type, but `getByeGroup` in `PlayOffTreeGen`and `DirectEliminationTreeGen`

So my initial though was to create a getByeGroup inside the DirectEliminationTeamTreeGen and call the parent, but it was a bad work around, and also, I realize that method is defined in the parent of `DirectEliminationTeamTreeGen` class but in the child of the calling class `TreeGen``

I understand the issue, as there is no getByeGroup() method inside `DirectEliminationTeamTreeGen` class, but don't know how to fix it.

Any Idea?

Comment: @teresko This deals about inheritance, not static methods. I don't know why PHP force to call it with :: it is weird syntax for me who come from Java Background

Comment: This deals with syntax and not OOP paradigm (and, yes, I initially made a mistake, but I still stand by my edition).

Comment: @tereško Ok for me ;)

Comment: Important detail that was not clear at first: are you trying to call *any* method from A, or are you trying to call a method from A that has been extended in B.  If the former, then simply calling `$this->parentMethod()` (as in shaggy's answer) will work.  If the latter (which I assumed because of your use of the parent keyword) then you will have to use my answer.  The `parent` keyword is only needed when you are trying to call a method in a parent that has been overridden in the child.  In all cases you can't call a parent method that is private.  In my answer the method must be public.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it this way.

```
class A{
    public function parentMethod() {
    }
}

class B extends A{
}

class C extends B{
    public function anotherMethod() {
        $this->parentMethod();
    }
}
```

If you want the method `parentMethod()` to be visible inside child class, the method has to be `public` (accessible from outside of the class) or `protected` (accessible only from inside - parent and child classes). `private` methods are only visible in the class in which they are defined.

More info here: [PHP visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: You should also explain how visibility affects it.

Comment: Your example gives a syntax error.  It also doesn't work in general.

Comment: yep, already tried it, but it doesn't work. All my method are protected

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro - try now. It was just simple example, I thought (looking at your reputation) you will figure out the whole code.
You need to call parent method inside another method (or `__construct`).

Comment: @shaggy then look at the tags .. it's android and laravel ... :D

Comment: @tereško - I know now, it was just quick answer (my bad).

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro if all of the methods are protected, then you wouldn't have any way to actually execute the logic inside a class. Especially, since putting logic in a constructors is considered to be a really terrible idea (due to testability issues)

Comment: @tereško when I say all method I refer to the children class in this case. And I have no logic at all in constructor, constuctor is not for that. I think reading the answers, that I have to rethink the way I organized all my classes. This question might give the answer to the wrong problem

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro favor composition over inheritance :P

Comment: I will rewrite my question with more details, as I think my initial question is not the good one. I don't know if it's posible to do that in stackoverflow, but I will try not alter the main question

Comment: Updated question. don't know if I should open a new question, or keep it here, @tereško what do you think?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro make a new one instead - because you have completely changed it

Comment: yep :( Sorry for all of you. I will create a new thread, I can't even delete this one

Comment: new thread here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190090/call-to-undefined-method-xoco70-kendotournaments-treegen-directeliminationteamtr

Answer (score -1):

You can call it directly

```
A::myMethod()
```

Generally though if you have to do that it is a sign that your setup may need some refactoring.

Note that while A::myMethod() works from inside of C, it does not work outside of C

```
class A{
    public function myMethod(){
        print 'a';
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public function myMethod(){
        print 'b';
    }
}

class C extends B{
    public function myMethod(){
        A::myMethod();
    }
}

$obj = new C();
$obj->myMethod();  // prints 'a'

A::myMethod();     // Deprecated: Non-static method A::myMethod() should not be called statically
```

The difference is that inside of C it is understood to be a reference to an ancestor.  Outside of C it is understood to be a static call, and A::myMethod is not a static function.